# Facebook graph api: Best database structure to hold the users data

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing the database for a web app which contains 2 ways for login, Standard way and social media  way.
I'm trying to find out the best design for the database to hold the users data.
Should I separate the users in separate tables depending on the type of the login or put them all on one table

I was thinking of this structure:

```
table1

-network //facebook, twitter, etc...
-user_network_id //user's id on the coorrespnding network
-user_id //user_id on our database

table2
-user_id //primary key
-username // account user name
- ....
- ....
```